# Call Microsoft Graph with application permissions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

When creating my .NET 7 project with Visual Studio I told it I was using Microsoft Identity and graph. The injected graph client works great for those items that have delegated permissions.  I have one method though where I need to make a call using application permissions, but I'm not sure how I would do that with the injected graph client.

Comment: can you provide code you have  tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension method `WithAppOnly` applied to a request and it expresses to use application permissions for the request.

```
await client.Users.Request().WithAppOnly().GetAsync();
```

If you need to set some specific scopes for the request, you can use extension method `WithScopes`.

```
await client.Users.Request().WithScopes(new [] { "xxx.yyy" } ).GetAsync();
```

You can combine `WithAppOnly` and `WithScopes`

```
await client.Users.Request().WithAppOnly().WithScopes(new [] { "xxx.yyy" } ).GetAsync();
```